# Android SDK (beta-10): intermittent issue with the player

Tags: android, spotify

First of all, I apologise for being so vague and for posting a question on an issue with such a limited scope. Hopefully I can elaborate on the contents of this question as we go along.

The problem is that in some cases a premium user is unable to play any content. The client passes all authentication checks (accessToken in SpotifyApi class is present and valid), but prompting playback doesn't result in any action (no playback and no error either).

Basically, the app prompts the player to play a list of 5 tracks `[com.spotify.sdk.android.player.Player:448]` at which point I am unable to debug any further and from my perspective the lifecycle ends there.

It is an intermittent issue--one account which did not work a couple of days ago is now working fine every time, no matter how many times I clean install the app. Another account encountered this issue for a couple of hours and then "magically" starter working as well, without changing anything in the app, re-installing or clearing data. Because the information returned by the SDK is scarce, I'm afraid I won't be able to provide any useful logging.

Any advice on how to at least troubleshoot this issue further would be greatly appreciated.